# How can you best convert a linear regression model (with the lm function) into logarithmic scale?

Tags: r

I have a linear model:

```
Model <- lm(`Cars` ~ `Contracts`, data = DF)
```

The data frame DF consists of a large data frame with many columns. "Cars" is one column that is meant to be the dependable (y) variable and "Contracts" is the independent variable (x).

I would like to model this in a log scale, so when I plot this model, it will appear with logarithmic values however I would also like to calculate the R-squared value of this logarithmic plot, hence why I need to convert the "lm" function to logarithmic so that I can use the "summary" function and retrieve the R-squared value. Is this possible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean you want to model this "in a log scale." Do you want to a model like  `E[log(Cars)] = int + log(Contracts)`?

Comment: @MrFlick: Ultimately, I just want to be able to see the linear regression in a log scaled plot and also be able to retrieve its r-squared value. I'm open for any method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When estimating just take the logarithm into the model.

***Example:***

```
library(ggplot2)  # includes diamonds data

fit <- lm(log(price) ~ carat, diamonds)

> coef(summary(fit))
            Estimate  Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 6.215021 0.003348400 1856.1164        0
carat       1.969757 0.003607758  545.9782        0
```

To plot with a logarithmic scale you can use `ggplot`'s `scale_y_log10()`:

```
ggplot(aes(x=carat, y=price), data=diamonds) +
  geom_jitter() +
  scale_y_log10()
```

*Produces:*

[image]

For logarithmic x axis use `scale_x_log10()` accordingly.